# Relation between models with composite keys

Tags: django, models, composite-key, relation

I have two models with composite keys:

```
class ContestUser(models.Model):
    user_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key = True)
    contest_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key = True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length = 1536, blank = True)
    .
    .
    .



class ContestRegistration(models.Model):
    user_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key = True)
    contest_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key = True)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices = EJUDGE_CONTEST_STATUSES)
    .
    .
    .
```

First question is How can I relate them, and query like in join.

Select * from ContestRegistration r join ContestUser u on r.user_id = u.user_id and r.contest_id = u.contest_id where r.contest_id = 3;

Second is How to save an object like this?

```
cuser = ContestUser.objects.get(user_id = 1, contest_id = 1)
cuser.username = 'username'
cuser.save()
```

This results in IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry '1-1' for key 'PRIMARY'")

Executed SQL is:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`contest_id` = 1  AND `users`.`user_id` = 1 );
SELECT (1) AS `a` FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`user_id` = 1  LIMIT 1;
UPDATE `users` SET ... WHERE `users`.`user_id` = 1 ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django models don't support multiple primary keys: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/faq/models/#do-django-models-support-multiple-column-primary-keys

However, as the documentation describes, you can use other properties on ForeignKey fields, like unique_together to do the same thing. Hope that helps you out.